# How to make Hive Terminal show rows (not just headers) after code is run?

Tags: hive, hiveql

As of now, Hive Terminal is showing only column headers after a `create table` code is run. What settings should I change to make Hive Terminal show few rows also, say first 100 rows?

Code I am using to create table `t2` from table `t1` which resides in the database (I don't know how t1 is created):

```
create table t2 as
select *
from t1
limit 100;
```

Now while development, I am writing `select * from t2 limit 100;` after each `create table` section to get the rows with headers.

Answer (score 1):

## You cannot

The [Hive Create Table documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable) does not mention anything about showing records. This, combined with my experience in Hive makes me quite confident that you cannot achieve this by mere regular config changes.

Of course you could tap into the code of hive itself, but that is not something to be attempted lightly.

## And you should not want to

Changing the create command could lead to all kinds of problems. Especially because unlike the select command, it is in fact an operation on metadata, followed by an insert. Both of these normally would not show you anything.

If you would create a huge table, it would be problematic to show everything. If you choose always to just show the first 100 rows, that would be inconsistent.

#### There are ways

Now, there are some things you could do:

1. Change hive itself (not easy, probably not desirable)
2. Do it in 2 steps (what you currently do)
3. Write a wrapper:

If you want to automate things and don't like code duplication, you can look into writing a small wrapper function to call the create and select based on just the input of source (and limit) and destination.

This kind of wrapper could be written in bash, python, or whatever you choose.

However, note that if you like executing the commands ad-hoc/manually this may not be suitable, as you will need to start a hive JVM each time you run such a program and thus response time is expected to be slow.

**All in all you are probably  best off just doing the create first and select second.**

Answer (score -1):

The below command mentioned seems to be correct to show the first 100 rows:

```
select * from <created_table> limit 100;
```

Paste the code you have written to create the table will help to diagnose the issue in hand!!

Nevertheless , check if you have correctly mentioned the delimiters for the elements, key-value pairs, collection items etc while creating the table.

If you have not defined them correctly you might end up with having only the first row(header) being shown.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question to include the code snippet I use to create table.

Comment: Mention the code snippet on how is the table t1 created?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't address the create (which was already mentioned subtly in the original question) so I have to downvote it.

Comment: @KeshavPradeepRamanath I want a solution which is independent of the way how table t1 is created. Assume that t1 is a table in the database and I don't know how t1 is created.